# Why are particular UDP messages always getting dropped below a particular buffer size?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp, vxworks

3 different messages are being sent to the same port at different rates:

<kbd>**Message**</kbd>  <kbd>**size (bytes)**</kbd>  <kbd>**Sent every**</kbd><kbd>**transmit speed**</kbd>
<kbd>High</kbd>           <kbd>232</kbd>                 <kbd>10 ms</kbd>          <kbd>100Hz</kbd>                  
<kbd>Medium</kbd>     <kbd>148</kbd>                 <kbd>20ms</kbd>           <kbd>50Hz</kbd>                    
<kbd>Low</kbd>            <kbd>20</kbd>                   <kbd>60 ms</kbd>          <kbd>16.6Hz</kbd>

I can only process one message every **~ 6 ms**.
Single threaded.  Blocking read.

---

A strange situation is occurring, and I don't have an explanation for it.
When I set my receive buffer to `4,799` bytes, all of my **low speed messages** get dropped.
I see maybe one or two get processed, and then nothing.

When I set my receive buffer to `4,800`(or higher!), it appears as though all of the low speed messages start getting processed.  I see about 16/17 a second.

---

This has been observed consistently.  The application sending the packets is always started before the receiving application. The receiving application always has a long delay after the sockets are created, and before it begins processing.  So the buffer is always full when the processing starts, and it is not the same starting buffer each time a test occurs.  This is because the socket is created after the sender is already sending out messages, so the receiver might start listening in the middle of a send cycle.

**Why does increasing the received buffer size a single byte, cause a huge change in low speed message processing?**

I built a table to better visualize the expected processing:
[image]

As some of these messages get processed, more messages presumably get put on the queue instead of being dropped.

Nonetheless, I would expect a `4,799` byte buffer to behave the same way as `4,800` bytes.

However that is not what I have observed.

---

I think the issue is related to the fact that low speed messages are sent at the same time as the other two messages.  It is always received after the high/medium speed messages.  (This has been confirmed over wireshark).

For example, assuming the buffer was empty to begin with,  it is clear that the low speed message would need queued longer than the other messages.
*1 message every 6ms is about 5 messages every 30ms.
[image]

This still doesn't explain the buffer size.

We are running VxWorks, and using their sockLib, which is an implementation of Berkeley sockets.  Here is a snippet of what our socket creation looks like:
**SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE** is what I'm changing.

```
struct sockaddr_in tSocketAddress;                          // Socket address
int     nSocketAddressSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);    // Size of socket address structure
int     nSocketOption = 0;

// Already created
if (*ptParameters->m_pnIDReference != 0)
    return FALSE;

// Create UDP socket
if ((*ptParameters->m_pnIDReference = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == ERROR)
{
    // Error
    CreateSocketMessage(ptParameters, "CreateSocket: Socket create failed with error.");

    // Not successful
    return FALSE;
}

// Valid local address
if (ptParameters->m_szLocalIPAddress != SOCKET_ADDRESS_NONE_STRING && ptParameters->m_usLocalPort != 0)
{
    // Set up the local parameters/port
    bzero((char*)&tSocketAddress, nSocketAddressSize);
    tSocketAddress.sin_len = (u_char)nSocketAddressSize;
    tSocketAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    tSocketAddress.sin_port = htons(ptParameters->m_usLocalPort);

    // Check for any address
    if (strcmp(ptParameters->m_szLocalIPAddress, SOCKET_ADDRESS_ANY_STRING) == 0)
        tSocketAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    else
    {
        // Convert IP address for binding
        if ((tSocketAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ptParameters->m_szLocalIPAddress)) == ERROR)
        {
            // Error
            CreateSocketMessage(ptParameters, "Unknown IP address.");

            // Cleanup socket
            close(*ptParameters->m_pnIDReference);
            *ptParameters->m_pnIDReference = ERROR;

            // Not successful
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // Bind the socket to the local address
    if (bind(*ptParameters->m_pnIDReference, (struct sockaddr *)&tSocketAddress, nSocketAddressSize) == ERROR)
    {
        // Error
        CreateSocketMessage(ptParameters, "Socket bind failed.");

        // Cleanup socket
        close(*ptParameters->m_pnIDReference);
        *ptParameters->m_pnIDReference = ERROR;

        // Not successful
        return FALSE;
    }
}

// Receive socket
if (ptParameters->m_eType == SOCKTYPE_RECEIVE || ptParameters->m_eType == SOCKTYPE_RECEIVE_AND_TRANSMIT)
{
    // Set the receive buffer size
    nSocketOption = SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE;
    if (setsockopt(*ptParameters->m_pnIDReference, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&nSocketOption, sizeof(nSocketOption)) == ERROR)
    {
        // Error
        CreateSocketMessage(ptParameters, "Socket buffer size set failed.");

        // Cleanup socket
        close(*ptParameters->m_pnIDReference);
        *ptParameters->m_pnIDReference = ERROR;

        // Not successful
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

and the socket receive that's being called in an infinite loop:
*The buffer size is definitely large enough

```
int SocketReceive(int nSocketIndex, char *pBuffer, int nBufferLength)
{
    int nBytesReceived = 0;
    char szError[256];

    // Invalid index or socket
    if (nSocketIndex < 0 || nSocketIndex >= SOCKET_COUNT || g_pnSocketIDs[nSocketIndex] == 0)
    {
        sprintf(szError,"SocketReceive: Invalid socket (%d) or ID (%d)", nSocketIndex, g_pnSocketIDs[nSocketIndex]);
        perror(szError);
        return -1;
    }

    // Invalid buffer length
    if (nBufferLength == 0)
    {
        perror("SocketReceive: zero buffer length");
        return 0;
    }

    // Send data
    nBytesReceived = recv(g_pnSocketIDs[nSocketIndex], pBuffer, nBufferLength, 0);

    // Error in receiving
    if (nBytesReceived == ERROR)
    {
        // Create error string
        sprintf(szError, "SocketReceive: Data Receive Failure: <%d> ", errno);

        // Set error message
        perror(szError);

        // Return error
        return ERROR;
    }

    // Bytes received
    return nBytesReceived;
}
```

**Any clues on why increasing the buffer size to 4,800 results in successful and consistent reading of low speed messages?**

Comment: *Nonetheless, 4,799 bytes is enough to expect the same behavior as 4,800 bytes.*  Why would you say that?  9,999 bytes isn't big enough to hold a 10,000-byte file.  *Any clues on why increasing the buffer size to 4,800 results in successful and consistent reading of low speed messages?*  It's not a clue, but I suspect it's because 4,800 butes is big enough, while 4,799 isn't.  You can either use a 4,800-byte buffer, or spend a lot of time and effort trying to get Wind River to tell you *why* you need to use a 4,800-byte buffer in your scenario - then you'll use a 4,800-byte buffer.

Comment: On the [setsockopt on vxworks](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/sockLib.html#setsockopt) page it states that "UDP reserves 41600 bytes, enough space for up to forty incoming datagrams (1 Kbyte each).". You're using 1/8.6th that, so enough space for around 4 packets. I suppose it all depends on the NIC and driver implementation - these usually use 'descriptor rings', with a number of packet buffers of a fixed size to hold most packets. If these are 1kb each (and larger packets get split into two or more buffers), receiving a bunch of smaller packets will exhaust the packet buffers.

Comment: Both 4799 and 4800 are far too small for practical socket receive buffers. You should've thinking in terms of 32-64k at least.

Comment: It is probably a switch problem -- something in the switch is configured to avoid flooding

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer to the question of why a `SO_RCVBUF` size of 4799 results in lost low speed messages and a size of 4800 works fine is that with the mixture of the UDP packets coming in, the rate at which they are coming in, the rate at which you are processing incoming packets, and the sizing of the `mbuff` and cluster numbers in your vxWorks kernel allow for sufficient network stack throughput that the low speed messages are not being discarded with the larger size.

The `SO_SNDBUF` option description in the `setsockopt()` man page at URL http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/sockLib.html#setsockopt mentioned in a comment above  has this to say about the size specified and the effect on `mbuff` usage:

> The effect of setting the maximum size of buffers (for both SO_SNDBUF
>   and SO_RCVBUF, described below) is not actually to allocate the mbufs
>   from the mbuf pool. Instead, the effect is to set the high-water mark
>   in the protocol data structure, which is used later to limit the
>   amount of mbuf allocation.

UDP packets are discrete units. If you send 10 packets of size 232 that is not considered to be 2320 bytes of data in contiguous memory. Instead that is 10 memory buffers within the network stack because UDP is discrete packets while TCP is a continuous stream of bytes.

See [How do I tune the network buffering in VxWorks 5.4?](https://community.rti.com/kb/how-do-i-tune-network-buffering-vxworks-54) in the DDS community web site which gives a discussion about the interdependence of the mixture of `mbuff` sizes and network clusters.

See [How do I resolve a problem with VxWorks buffers?](https://community.rti.com/kb/how-do-i-resolve-problem-vxworks-buffers) in the DDS community web site.

See this PDF of a slide presentation, [A New Tool to study Network Stack Exhaustion in VxWorks](http://www-acc.kek.jp/epics_gr/epicsasia2004/ppt/dec10/dec10-thompson-networkstack.pdf) from 2004 which discusses using various tools such as `mBufShow` and `inetStatShow` to see what is happening in the network stack.

Answer (score 0):

Without detailed analysis of every network stack implementation along the path your UDP messages are being sent it is nearly impossible to state the resulting behaviour.

UDP implementations are allowed to drop any packet at their own discretion. Usually this happens when a stack comes to the conclusion that it would need to drop packets to be able to receive new ones. There is no formal requirement that the packets dropped are the oldest or the newest being received. It could also be that a certain size class is more affected due to internal memory management strategies.

From the IP stacks involved the most interesting one is the one on the receiving machine.

For sure you will get better receive experience if you change the receive side to have a receive buffer that will take several seconds full of expected messages. I'd start with at least 10k.

The observed "change" in behaviour when going from 4,799 to 4,800 may result from the later just allowing one of the small messages to be received before it needs to be dropped again, while the smaller size just causes it to be dropped slightly earlier. If the receiving application is quick enough to read the pending message you will receive small messages in the one case and no small messages in the other case.